# CSS crop string in the middle

Tags: html, css

I have a big filename that I'm cropping using css text-overflow: ellipsis.

```
<style>
   #fileName {
      width: 100px;
      white-space: nowrap;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
      overflow: hidden;
  }
</style>
<div id="fileName"> This is the big name of my file.txt</div>
```

So I have this output

> This is the bi...

But I want to preserve the file extension and have something like this

> This is the... le.txt

Is it possible only using CSS?

Since my files are always txt, I've tried to use `text-overflow: string`, but it looks like it only works on Firefox:

```
 text-overflow: '*.txt';
```

Comment: No. The only way to do something like that is through Javascript.

Comment: could you just put the file extension in a different container?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Here is a clean CSS solution using the [`data-*` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) and two `::after` pseudo-elements. I also added an optional hover and show all text (the `#fileName::after` pseudo element needs to be removed when the full text is shown).

#### Example 1

```css
#fileName {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
}

#fileName p {
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#fileName:after {
  content: attr(data-filetype);
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}


/*Show on hover*/

#fileName:hover {
  width: auto
}

#fileName:hover:after {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="fileName" data-filetype="txt">
  <p>This is the big name of my file.txt</p>
</div>
```

---

### Going further — hiding the appended filetype when the filename is short

The `#fileName p::after` is given a background color that matches the background of the text. This covers the ".txt" when the filenames are short and therefore not cut off with `overflow: hidden`.

Note the `padding-right: 22px`, this pushes the ".txt" beyond the ellipsis.

Refer to examples 2 and 3 below for different methods with different browser support for each. It doesn't seem to be possible to hide the ".txt" happily in all browsers.

#### Example 2

**Browser Compatibility:** Chrome and Firefox.

The `#fileName p::after` is given a background color that matches the background of the text. This covers the ".txt" when the filenames are short and therefore not cut off with `overflow: hidden`.

Note the `padding-right` on each of the `::after` pseudo-elements. `padding-right: 22px` pushes the ".txt" beyond the ellipsis and `padding-right: 100%` gives the covering pseudo-element its width. The `padding-right: 100%` doesn't work with Edge or IE 11.

```css
#fileName {
  position: relative;
  width: 122px;
}

#fileName::after {
  content: attr(data-filetype);
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

#fileName p {
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-right: 22px;
}

#fileName p::after {
  content: '';
  background: #FFF;
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

/*Show on hover*/

#fileName:hover {
  width: auto;
}


/*Hide .txt on hover*/

#fileName:hover::after {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="fileName" data-filetype=".txt">
  <p>This is the big name of my file.txt</p>
</div>

<div id="fileName" data-filetype=".txt">
  <p>Short.txt</p>
</div>
```

#### Example 3

**Browser Compatibility:** IE 11, Edge and Chrome.

The `content: ... unholy amount of ...` on `#fileName p::after` gives it width. This, along with `display: inline-block`, is currently the only method that works on the Edge browser / IE 11 as well as Chrome. The `display: inline-block` breaks this method on Firefox and the `.txt` is not covered on short filenames.

```css
#fileName {
  position: relative;
  width: 122px;
}

#fileName::after {
  content: attr(data-filetype);
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding-right: 10px; /*Fixes Edge Browser*/
}

#fileName p {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-right: 22px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

#fileName p::after {
  content: '.........................................................................................................................';/*Fixes Edge Browser*/
  background: #FFF;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;/*Fixes Edge Browser*/
  z-index: 1;
  color: #FFF;
}


/*Show on hover*/

#fileName:hover {
  width: auto
}

#fileName:hover::after {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="fileName" data-filetype=".txt">
  <p>This is the big name of my file.txt</p>
</div>

<div id="fileName" data-filetype=".txt">
  <p>Short.txt</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I wonder if this can be improved to support non-overflowing text. If `filename.txt` happens to be short and does not cause ellipsis to appear, the `:after`'s `txt` is still going to show.

Comment: @GSerg I have revised my answer (quite a long time later) with an improved solution that deals with this. Check it out in my answer above :)

Answer (score 13):

This is the best I can come up with... It might be worthwhile trying to clean up the leading edge of the second span...

**CSS**

```
#fileName span {
      white-space: nowrap;
      overflow: hidden;
      display:inline-block;
 }
#fileName span:first-child {
      width: 100px;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
 }
#fileName span + span {
      width: 30px;
      direction:rtl;
      text-align:right;
 }
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="fileName">
    <span>This is the big name of my file.txt</span>
    <span>This is the big name of my file.txt</span>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c8everqm/1/

Comment: very interesting solution !

Comment: Not very useful in case the text can be either short or long

Answer (score 12):

Here is another suggestion that worked well for me:

```
<div style="width:100%;border:1px solid green;display:inline-flex;flex-wrap:nowrap;">
   <div style="flex: 0 1 content;text-overflow: ellipsis;overflow:hidden;white-space:nowrap;"> Her comes very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long </div>
   <div style="flex: 1 0 content;white-space:nowrap;"> &nbsp;but flexible line</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I like that approach. Created a fiddle and cleaned it up a bit + removed that `flex-basis: content;` as its support isn't great atm. [link](http://jsfiddle.net/4ah8ernc/2/)

Comment: Took me a while to get this working with wkhtmltopdf (old webkit) as the autoprefixer did it's job but the values were in the wrong "order". So here's another fiddle with a version working with wkhtmltopdf 0.12.4 [link](http://jsfiddle.net/4ah8ernc/3/)

Comment: Should use "white-space: pre;" instead, else the last space character will not be preserved when shown in the browser between 2 <div>s

Answer (score 8):

Here's a solution that uses `flexbox`, and is dynamic, (e.g. works when the user resizes the browser window). Disadvantage is that the text after the ellipsis has a fixed size, so you can't put the ellipsis in the exact middle of the text.

### CSS

```
.middleEllipsis {
    margin: 10px;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}
.start {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    flex-shrink: 1;
}
.end {
    white-space: nowrap;
    flex-basis: content;
    flex-grow: 0;
    flex-shrink: 0;

}
```

### HTML

```
<div class="middleEllipsis">
    <div class="start">This is a really long file name, really long really long really long</div><div class="end">file name.txt</div>
</div>
```

Resize the right-hand side boxes on jsfiddle to see the effect:

https://jsfiddle.net/L9sy4dwa/1/

If you're willing to abuse `direction: rtl`, you can even get the ellipsis right in the middle of the text with some small changes to your CSS:

```
.middleEllipsis {
    margin: 10px;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}
.middleEllipsis > .start {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    flex-shrink: 1;
}
.middleEllipsis > .end {
    white-space: nowrap;
    flex-basis: content;
    flex-grow: 0;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    align: right;
    overflow: hidden;
    direction: rtl;
}
```

You can see an animated gif of what this looks like on https://i.stack.imgur.com/CgW24.gif.

Here's a jsfiddle showing this approach:

https://jsfiddle.net/b8seyre3/

Comment: Solid answer! Was able to solve a third party component with this solution, although I had to add min-width: 0 to ancestors and other trickery

Answer (score 2):

I tried some of those CSS approach but the problem is if the text is short, you will get "short text      short text" instead of "short text".

So I went with CSS + JS approach.
JS (I edited Jeremy Friesen's to fix some cases):

```js
const shrinkString = (originStr, maxChars, trailingCharCount) => {
    let shrinkedStr = originStr;
    const shrinkedLength = maxChars - trailingCharCount - 3;
    if (originStr.length > shrinkedLength) {
      const front = originStr.substr(0, shrinkedLength);
      const mid = '...';
      const end = originStr.substr(-trailingCharCount);
      shrinkedStr = front + mid + end;
    }

    return shrinkedStr;
}
```

HTML:

```html
<div>
  <h5>{shrinkString("can be very long of short text", 50, 15)}&nbsp;</h5>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

I hope it helps. Sorry for the format. This is my first answer on SO.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript option:

```
var cropWithExtension = function(value, maxChars, trailingCharCount) {
    var result = value;

    if(value.length > maxChars){
        var front = value.substr(0, value.length - (maxChars - trailingCharCount - 3));
        var mid = "...";
        var end = value.substr(-trailingCharCount);

        result = front + mid + end;
    }

    return result;
}

var trimmedValue = cropWithExtension("This is the big file.txt", 21, 6);
```

Answer (score 0):

Input ---This is a very very very very very big file.txt

To truncate the above file name use the below javascript

Output ---This is a very...big file.txt

---

```
var selectedFileName = getItemSelected();//Input

$scope.referenceFileName =getItemSelected();

var len = selectedFileName.length;

if(len > 30){
 selectedFileName = selectedFileName.substr(0,15)+'... '+selectedFileName.substr(len-15,15);    
}

$scope.fileName = selectedFileName;
```

---

**

> Note:

**Pass the $scope.referenceFileName in the json---back end

`$scope.fileName` this would be---front end

Comment: This is another suggestion

Answer (score 0):

The accept answer is good. Although for Browser Compatibility, you could do the detection for truncate or not. Make the whole CSS conditional.

```
const wrap = document.getElementById('filenameText');
  if (wrap.offsetWidth >= wrap.scrollWidth) {
    this.truncation = false;
  }

 <div
    :data-filetype="data-filetype"
    :class="[truncation && 'truncateFilenamClass']"
  >
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out the css solutions quite buggy and hard to maintain, since you need to add attributes or elements to separate text.

I built a quite straight forward Javascript that handles it. Send your text and max length of the text and you get the text truncated in the middle back.

```
const truncateMiddle = (text, maxCharacters) => {
  const txtLength = text.length; // Length of the incoming text
  const txtLengthHalf = maxCharacters ? Math.round(maxCharacters / 2) : Math.round(txtLength / 2); // set max txtHalfLength
  return text.substring(0, (txtLengthHalf -1)).trim() + '...' + text.substring((txtLength - txtLengthHalf) + 2, txtLength).trim() //Return the string
}
```

```
truncateMiddle('Once opon a time there was a little bunny', 10);
```

Returns: ***Once...nny***

Cons? Sure, it need more functionality to be responsive.

Answer (score 0):

CSS is good, but I think you must do it by JavaScript for more accurate results.
Why?
Because, with JS You can control number of first and last texts of words.
This is just 2 lines of JavaScript code to crop string as per you define:-

```js
    let fileName=document.getElementById('fileName')
    fileName.innerHTML=fileName.innerHTML.substring(1, 10)+'...'+fileName.innerHTML.slice(-2)
```

```html
 <div id="fileName"> This is the big name of my file.txt</div>
```

also, you can choose first `n` words, instead of first few letter/characters with JS, as per you want.
whose JS code is this:-

```js
    let fileName=document.getElementById('fileName')
    let Words=fileName.innerHTML.split(" ")
    let i=0;
    fileName.innerHTML=''
    Words.forEach(e => {
        i++
        if(i<5)
        fileName.innerHTML+=e+' ' 
    });
    fileName.innerHTML+='...'
```

```html
 <div id="fileName"> This is the big name of my file.txt</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

For a solution that works with liquid layouts I came up with something that uses flexbox. Obvious drawback is that three elements are needed. Obvious advantage: If there is enough room everything will be shown. Depending on circumstances an additional white-space rule for the paragraph might be needed as well as some min-width for the first span.

```
<p><span>Long text goes in here except for the</span><span>very end</span></p>

p {display:flex}
p span:first-child {flex-shrink:1; text-overflow: ellipsis; overflow: hidden}
```

ADDENDUM: Strictly speaking, the flex-shrink is not even necessary because it is the default behaviour of the flex-items anyway. This is not so in IE10, however. Prefixing is necessary, too in this case.