# How to apply css of specific column.

Tags: javascript, css, extjs

I am trying to implement this css in my Grid.

[CSS crop string in the middle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27746218/css-crop-string-in-the-middle)

Now this is working at some extend. (Not exactly) By using this cls.

```
.x-grid-cell-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
}
.x-grid-cell-inner p {
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.x-grid-cell-inner:after {
  content: attr(data-filetype);
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
/*Show on hover*/
.x-grid-cell-inner:hover {
  width: auto  
}
.x-grid-cell-inner:hover:after {
  display: none;  
}
```

But th problem is this is appraring all the column and widgetColumn. I want to apply this wherever column type is "textfield". For this I am trying

```
renderer: function (value, meta, record) {
        meta.tdAttr = 'data-qtip="' + value + '"';
        if(meta.column.filterType == "autoresolve"){
            meta.tdCls = "x-grid-cell-inner"
        }
        return value;
    }
```

I need to change the `x-grid-cell-inner` name as well but I am giving the it is not coming. 
But by using this it is getting apply to all the cells. I want to avoid those cells whose column type is not "textfield". Can anybody help to get that.

Comment: I think this could be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem#answer-66378). What do you want to achieve? How is your widget column defined?

Comment: Can you add a sample fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **tdCls** attribute of columns. For example, if you set **tdCls: 'fiddle-overflow-cell'** to your column then your style will be

```
.fiddle-overflow-cell .x-grid-cell-inner {
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
}

.fiddle-overflow-cell .x-grid-cell-inner p {
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.fiddle-overflow-cell .x-grid-cell-inner:after {
    content: attr(data-filetype);
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
}
/*Show on hover*/

.fiddle-overflow-cell .x-grid-cell-inner:hover {
    width: auto
}

.fiddle-overflow-cell .x-grid-cell-inner:hover:after {
    display: none;
}
```

fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2cns

You can add the attribute on all the columns that need this behaviour or define a custom xtype:

```
    Ext.define('Fiddle.grid.column.TextColumn', {
        extend: 'Ext.grid.column.Column',
        xtype: 'textcolumn',

        tdCls: 'fiddle-overflow-cell'
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for answer.

Comment: As you notice in the link given in question, I want my text should be broken in middle, not in last. Any css hack.