# Long words breaking in the middle of div using [...]

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, frontend

I want to create JS function that will allow me to controll to long file names in div with out using stadard [...] in the end using:

```
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
white-space: nowrap;
```

[Example of what i dont want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVMdG.png)
I want too long file names to look something like this:
AASDASDASDASD...ASDASDFA.TXT

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS crop string in the middle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27746218/css-crop-string-in-the-middle)

Comment: You can write generic function which accepts in the parameters: fileName, fileNameMaxLength, charachtersQuantityBefore3Dots, charachtersQuantityAfter3Dots. So that you can specify requirenments for file name on every call. I can write implementation if you want