# Fixing span double appearance and letter cutting

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, frontend

hello i am trying to make span that allows me to trim too long words in the middle:

[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClH7O.png)

but the problem is if the word is long the letters are being cut in the middle:

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPKoE.png)

and if the word is short it appears twice:

[example2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4qqy.png)

css:

```
#attachmentfile span {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
}

#attachmentfile span:first-child {
    width: 50%;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

#attachmentfile span + span {
    width: 50%;
    direction: rtl;
    text-align: right;
}
```

html:

```
<span>
    {{Att}}
</span>
<span>
    {{Att}}
</span>
```

sample: http://jsfiddle.net/c8everqm/1/

Comment: The question asked maybe a duplicate of **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4250364/how-to-trim-a-file-extension-from-a-string-in-javascript**

Comment: i searched for it but i couldnt find answer this one doesnt help but thanks.

Comment: i added sample @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: It's only polite to include the source of your code / attribution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27746353/2181514

Comment: There's a number of possible solutions already in SO, eg: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36470401/2181514  what made you pick this solution (in the question) to try to "fix"?

Comment: If you don't mind `... ...` you could add `text-overflow: ellipsis;` to the second span http://jsfiddle.net/d51q8zso/ to fix letters cut in half - and then probably set both to 50% - still won't fix other issues caused by having 2 spans - essentially, a 2 span solution doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

**Css:**

```
#fileName span {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}

#fileName span:first-child {
  width: 100px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

#fileName span + span {
  width: 1px;
  direction: rtl;
  text-align: right;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="fileName"><span>This is the big name of my file.txt</span><span>This is the big name of my file.txt</span>
</div>
```

Thanks to `freedomn-m` this is as far as I got to the solution.

http://jsfiddle.net/ygqz3b5k/1/

Comment: @Fanso98 instead of `width:1px` you could use `width:0px` it will be helpful for you to get your output.

Answer (score 0):

I propose the following solution:

**CSS:**

```
.cut-text { 
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden; 
  width: 160px; 
  height: 1.2em; 
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="cut-text">
    This text is a bit long, so 3 dots will appear.
</div>
```

```css
.cut-text { 
  display: inline-block;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden; 
  width: 170px;  
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="cut-text">
This text is a bit long so 3 dots will appear.
</div>
```