# How to shorten string to dots inbetween beginning and ending of string

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wonder how I would shorten the text seen below to fit its container. The width of the container varies, depending on screen size. In order to fit its container, the strings inbetween the first and last words shall be replaced by as many dots as needed in order for it to fit the container, so something like `Sydney - ... - Quito`. Ideally, it only replaces whole words (like `Doha`, `Singapur`, ...) and preserves the dash `-` after the first word/before the last word.

```css
.container {
    background-color: hotpink;
    width: 200px;
    white-space: nowrap
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <p class='route'>Sydney - Doha - Singapur - Capetown - Quito</p>
</div>
```

Is there a CSS and/or JvaScript solution for this?

Comment: If you can make the structure something like `<p class='route'><span>Sydney - Doha - Singapur - Capetown</span><span> - Quito</span></p>`, that can work. I don't think there's a native CSS way to omit _the middle_ of text.

Comment: related W3C proposal: https://www.w3.org/wiki/Text-overflow_middle_cropping - currently it is not possible with CSS alone.

Comment: @deceze that would absolutly be possible

Comment: For completeness, I was aiming at a solution like this from the dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37722624/476

Comment: I found this repo, which does it (with a lof of efford though): https://github.com/definite2/truncate-middle

Comment: @four-eyes hey! I've made an example with little of JS of how it can be achieved. - https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-flower-9h0zpt?file=/src/js/index.js . In real life I advice you to use it with `debounce` method to not trigger calculations on every resize tick

Answer (score 0):

```js
function truncateText(container) {
  const text = container.innerText;
  const containerWidth = container.clientWidth;
  const words = text.split(' ');
  let truncatedText = '';

  for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    const tempText = truncatedText + ' ' + words[i];
    container.innerText = tempText + '...';
    if (container.scrollWidth > containerWidth) {
      container.innerText = truncatedText + '...';
      break;
    }
    truncatedText = tempText;
  }
}


truncateText(document.getElementById('container'))
```

```css
#container {
  width: 220px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  content content content content content content content content content
</div>
```